# Running Avahi Docker linux container in windows

Tags: windows, docker, dbus, avahi, dns-sd

I wanted to make a cross-platform solution for a DNS-sd client. I've chose to use Avahi in Linux and then maybe in a docker container in windows (for some reason, solutions like Bonjour are not fit for my purpose. Since Avahi needs to call the  D-bus in Linux, I was wondering if anyone know how to solve this issue with docker containers in windows so one can use Avahi as well in windows using docker Container.

Thank you.